# Proving that a 5-regular graph with ten vertices is non planar

Tags: graph-theory

How can we prove that a 5-regular graph with ten vertices is non planar? Do we use $E \leq 3V-6$?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  What is a regular graph? How many edges are there? You need the handshaking lemma.